# How to call the same JavaScript function repeatedly while waiting for the function to run its course before invoking it again, using method chaining?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

Using method chaining, I am looking to fire a function repeatedly but only after the function has completed. Almost like don't execute until the function has fully run its course. Example of intended result:

```
var myfunc = {
    copy: function(message){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(message);
        },1000);
        return this;
    }
};
myfunc.copy('hello').copy('world'); 
// wait a second then log:
// hello
// wait until first function completion (1000ms), wait a second then log:
// world
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery you can also have it as a pure JS solution.

```js
var myfunc = {
   timer: null,
   stack: [],
   copy: function(val) {
       if(this.timer == null) {
         console.log(val);
         target.innerHTML += val+"<br />";
         this.timer = setTimeout(function(){myfunc.onComplete();},1000);
       }
       else
         this.stack.push(val);
     
       return this;
   },
   onComplete: function() {
      var val = this.stack.shift();
      console.log(val);
      target.innerHTML += val+"<br />";
      if(this.stack.length) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){myfunc.onComplete();}, 1000);
      }
      else this.timer = null;
   }
};

var target = document.getElementById('target');
var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');

trigger.onclick = function(){
  myfunc.copy("hello").copy("world");
}
```

```html
<button id="trigger">Start</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

A working model with variable timeouts:

```js
var myfunc = {
    // the queue for commands waiting for execution
    queue: [],

    // (public) combined method for waiting 1000 ms and the displaying the message
    copy: function (message, wait) {
        // have a look for queue length
        var started = myfunc.queue.length;
        // push wait method with value if set or 1000 ms to queue
        myfunc.queue.push(myfunc.wait(wait || 1000));
        // push write message to queue
        myfunc.queue.push(myfunc.write(message));
        // if queue was empty, continuing command call has not started, get next commmand
        started || myfunc.next();
        // return whole object for chaining
        return this;
    },

    // set a timeout for the next next call
    wait: function (m) {
        return function () {
            setTimeout(myfunc.next, m);
        };
    },

    // do some action, here write message and call next
    write: function (message) {
        return function () {
            // present the message
            console.log(message);
            // call next command in queue
            myfunc.next();
        }
    },

    // the fabulous next method. calls the next command and delete it form the queue
    next: function () {
        // test if queue has a command to call, then shift the queue and call the function
        myfunc.queue.length && myfunc.queue.shift()();
    },
};
myfunc.copy('to').copy('be').copy('or', 2000).copy('not').copy('to').copy('be');
myfunc.copy('that', 3000).copy('is').copy('the', 2000).copy('question');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Is there no way to store passed message(s) into an array to fire again after completion. So if it is fired again, it stores the new message in an array. Once initial completion, checks array to see if there are more values, then re-fires function using the next value in said array? I apologize if that sounds confusing.

Maybe this is a solution for you:

```js
var myfunc = {
    queue: [],
    index: -1,

    copy: function (message, wait) {
        var started = myfunc.queue.length;
        myfunc.queue.push(myfunc.wait(wait || 1000));
        myfunc.queue.push(myfunc.write(message));
        started || myfunc.next();
        return this;
    },

    wait: function (m) {
        return function () {
            setTimeout(myfunc.next, m);
        };
    },

    write: function (message) {
        return function () {
            console.log(message);
            myfunc.next();
        }
    },

    next: function () {
        myfunc.index++;
        myfunc.index %= myfunc.queue.length;
        myfunc.queue[myfunc.index]();
    },
};

function go(i) {
    [
        function () { myfunc.copy('to').copy('be'); },
        function () { myfunc.copy('  or', 2000).copy('  not').copy('  to').copy('  be'); },
        function () { myfunc.copy('    that', 3000).copy('    is').copy('    the', 2000).copy('    question'); }
    ][i]();
}

go(0);
setTimeout(go, 5000, 1);
setTimeout(go, 20000, 2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is it OK to use answer idea for [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38159455/3078890).

Comment: @mortezaT, it's ok for me.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for Promises, though not supported across the board yet, you can use babel or traceur (or even jQuery's deferred) to use them now:

```
var myfunc = {
  copy: function(message) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(message);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

// sequential processing
myfunc.copy('hello').then(function(message1) {
  console.log(message1);
  myfunc.copy('world').then(function(message2) {
    console.log(message2);
  });
});

// batch processing
Promise.all([myfunc.copy('hello'), myfunc.copy('world')]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values.join(' '));
});
```

Reference: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [Promise.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Thanks Rob M. Is there no way to store passed message(s) into an array to fire again after completion. So if it is fired again, it stores the new message in an array. Once initial completion, checks array to see if there are more values, then re-fires function using the next value in said array? I apologize if that sounds confusing.

Comment: Most lucid answer in my opinion, I think the poster is asking for an impossible mix of synchronous and asynchronous processings.