# Complete all functions inside a FOR LOOP before iterating to next iteration of the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout, es6-promise

Say i have a function like :

```
var bigArray = [1,2,3,4,5.........n];
for(var i=0; i<bigArray.length; i++){
  if(someCondition){
     setTimeout(function(){
       ..do_stuff..
       callSomeFunction();
     }, someDelayTime);
  }

  if(someCondition){
     setTimeout(function(){
       ..do_stuff..
       callSomeFunction();
     }, someDelayTime);
  }

  if(someCondition){
     setTimeout(function(){
       ..do_stuff..
       callSomeFunction();
     }, someDelayTime);
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  if(someCondition){
     setTimeout(function(){
       ..do_stuff..
       callSomeFunction();
     }, someDelayTime);
  }
}
```

Now what i want from this function is that when all of the conditions have performed their intended task, only then it should move to the next iteration of FOR loop. In other words, `i=0` in FOR LOOP should change to `i=1` and so-on iff all of the conditions inside the FOR loop have completed their job in current iteration.
Currently behaviour of this code is very random (because of `setTimeout` i believe). How can i make this work as per my expectations?

I recently read about promises (don't know much about them) but i'm not sure how to implement them in this code or if they will work in this case...

Comment: You cannot mix synchronous loops with asynchronous behavior like that. What you probably want to do is map promises to an array and sequence them.

Comment: Sorry but since i've very few understanding of promises, i'm unable to interpret the solution you are suggesting. Thanks for quick response though!

Comment: @TusharShukla I think it would be good to upvote original idea too.

Comment: @mortezaT I believe you're speaking of ACCEPTED answer. Well i really appreciate everyone's help and i'm thankful to them however i still haven't solved this problem as per requirements of my code. Of Course i'll accept an answer once i figure out the solution.

Comment: @TusharShukla Then what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original idea came from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081949/how-to-call-the-same-javascript-function-repeatedly-while-waiting-for-the-functi/32082676#32082676) of [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) on some similar question.
this answer is good if you don't like promises and deferred object. Othewise **Kris Kowal**'s [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) would be a better choice.

```js
function Iterator() {
  var iterator = this;
  this.queue = [];

  this.add = function(callback, wait) {
    iterator.queue.push(iterator.wait(wait));

    iterator.queue.push(function() {
      callback();
      iterator.next();
    });
  };

  this.wait = function(wait) {
    return function() {
      setTimeout(iterator.next, wait);
    };
  };

  this.next = function() {
    iterator.queue.length && iterator.queue.shift()();
  };
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  counter = -1;

var iterator = new Iterator();

(function fillNextIteration() {
  if (counter >= arr.length)
    return;
  counter++;
  iterator.add(function() {
    console.log('1 - counter value is ' + counter);
  }, 100);
  iterator.add(function() {
    console.log('2 - counter value is ' + counter);
  }, 100);
  iterator.add(function() {
    console.log('3 - counter value is ' + counter);
  }, 100);
  iterator.add(function() {
    console.log('4 - counter value is ' + counter);
  }, 100);

  iterator.add(fillNextIteration, 100);
  iterator.next();

})();
```

### Code Explanation

Iterator class has one queue which is and array and some methods:

**next**

when you call `next()` if there is any callback in queue it will fetch first and execute that. when you call [Array#shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) it removes and returns first item from array. When this item is a function then you can invoke it by adding parentheses in front of it. here is the expanded version:

```
if (iterator.queue.length > 0) {
    var callback = iterator.queue.shift();
    callback();
}
```

**wait**

This method will add an extra callback to queue which after a timeout calls the next method. this one is for creating the expected delay.

**add**
This method calls the wait with desired delay then attaches another function to queue which will call the callback and then calls next to make callback chain running.

---

**fillNextIteration**
after explaining the iterator there is another loop here on function `fillNextIteration` this starts with the conditions for the first iteration for example:

```
if (someConditionIsTrue) {
    iterator.add(function() {
        doWhatShallBeDone;
    }, delay);
}
```

you can check all conditions and then if required add the callback as shown.
after all condition finished add `fillNextIteration` as last action to continue the loop.

**self invoking function**
As you can see `fillNextIteration` is self invoked.
This helps to reduce one invoke and works like this:

```
function f(){};
f();
```

**Last thing to mention**
you can create a loop by calling a function inside itself. if there is no delay or stop for revoke then it would be a deadlock. So this is another loop as well:

```
(function loop() { setTimeout(loop, delay); })();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code, i'm quite not well versed with this style of js code. (No offence i mean).

Comment: @TusharShukla Some note added. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now i can use this for my desired purpose. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this please :

```
bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.........n];
neededStuff = 10; // Number of finished works you need below
stuffOK = neededStuff;
function mainFunction(i) {

    function loopFunction(i) {
        if (someCondition) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // .. do_stuff..
                stuffOK++;
                callSomeFunction();
            }, someDelayTime);
        }

        if (someCondition) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // .. do_stuff..
                stuffOK++;
                callSomeFunction();
            }, someDelayTime);
        }

        if (someCondition) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // .. do_stuff..
                stuffOK++;
                callSomeFunction();
            }, someDelayTime);
        }
        /*

         ...

         */

        if(someCondition) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // .. do_stuff..
                stuffOK++;
                callSomeFunction();
            }, someDelayTime);
        }
    }

    if (stuffOK == neededStuff) {
        i++;
        stuffOK = 0; // reinit counter
        loopFunction(i);
    }

    setTimeout('mainFunction(' + i + ');', 100);

}
mainFunction(-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work from promise chaning

```
callSomeFunction1().then(function() {
   callSomeFunction2();
}).then(function() {
   callSomeFunction3();
})
```