# javascript loops with delay between iterations using while

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need this loop to run forever, a `while` loop, checking the status of something every ten seconds. So, a `for` loop is not part of the real solution - but I am using a `for` loop in this example to avoid hanging the browser.

How can this code be structured with an outer `while` loop, and with a five-second delay between each loop iteration and a 3-second delay each time the waitx function is called.

The desired output is:

```
display loop counter
wait 5 seconds
display curr time
wait 3 seconds
display time diff
(loop) display next loop counter
etc.
```

```js
//$('body').css('background','wheat'); //test if js is broken 
function waitx(truck){
  console.log(truck);
  $('div').html(truck);
  setTimeout(function(){
    newnow = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = newnow - truck;
    console.log(diff);
    $('div').html(diff); //unwanted - just shows what SHOULD happen below
    return diff;
  },3000);
}

for (var nn=1; nn<6; nn++){
  console.log(nn);
  setTimeout(function(){
    now = new Date().getTime(); //1479575397219
    bonk = waitx(now);
    //$('div').html(bonk + " hello"); //how to get this to work?
  },5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle for playing with**](https://jsfiddle.net/gabus1y2/)</kbd>

Comment: you may have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081949/how-to-call-the-same-javascript-function-repeatedly-while-waiting-for-the-functi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a function that calls itself over and over again

```js
(function waitx(i) {
    console.log('loop counter : ' + i);
    setTimeout(function() {
     var now = new Date().getTime();
     console.log('current time : ' + now);
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            var diff = new Date().getTime() - now;
            console.log('time diff : ' + diff);
            waitx(++i);
        }, 3000)
    },5000);
}(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
display loop counter
wait 5 seconds
display curr time
wait 3 seconds
display time diff
(loop) display next loop counter
etc.
*/

(function startLoop(counter) {
  console.log(counter);
  
  setTimeout(function wait5Seconds() {
    console.log(Date.now());
    
    setTimeout(function wait3Seconds() {
      console.log(Date.now());
      startLoop(++counter);
    }, 3000);
  }, 5000);
})(0);
```