# How to make animation in JS for choosing value from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have 3 numbers [1, 2, 3]

Then I am running JS random function and JS choosing one of these number. I have done this part and it doesn't seems for me hard.

But now I want to create animation in JS/jQuery, for example,

I am put one of these three numbers to variable and my animation function should start changing numbers (loop through an array) in div during 3 second. But the speed shouldn't be constant. Number changing should be slowing down until 3 seconds pass. Then it should stop at the my number from variable.

Can you please give me some examples how can I achieve this result? I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: maybe you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32081949/1447675

Comment: Nina, this topic is a little bit different. The main question is how to make it running with acceleration. Not printing each number in DOM. I want to make a function which will loop through an array for 3 second by rewriting one DOM element (for example span) with slowing down and stop after three second at specific number. Something like in games when you are getting random prize. It runs like carousel fast then slowing down and stops at your random prize.

Answer (score 0):

For a increasing Speed, you could take a factor for the interval and an Offset for the sum of all intervals before that interval.

You could Experiment with the start interval and/or the factor.

```js
var array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    interval = 1400,
    p = 0;

array.forEach((v, i) => setTimeout(_ => document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = v, (interval /= 1.5, p += interval)));
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: This is not what I am want to do. I want to run JS throgh array in loop { show 1, show 2, show 3, do it again } for 3 seconds. And then stop at specific value. Acceleration should be a part of this loop. It starts fast then slowing down and stops at my value from this array. I think the function should calculate get time variable (3 sec), amount of elements (here there are 3) and then do your function with loop. I tried but it is not working at all.