# Pausing and Resuming an Interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I current have a series of intervals running to update animations and check variables in JS. I'm trying to make it so it pauses when I swap to another screen (clearinterval), and resume when I return to the screen.

I'm able to pause it at the moment, but can't seem to resume it.

Could anyone please help? Much appreciated in advance

These intervals are running as soon as the page loads:

```
var hungerCountdown = setInterval(increaseHunger, 10000);
var changeHungerMood = setInterval(changeHungerMood, 5000);
var mistakeCheck = setInterval(mistakeCheck, 5000);
```

I am using the following to pause the counters

```
function pauseCounters() {
clearInterval(hungerCountdown);
clearInterval(changeHungerMood);
clearInterval(mistakeCheck);
}
```

And trying to resume the counters with this

```
function resumeCounters() {
hungerCountdown = setInterval(increaseHunger, 10000);
changeHungerMood = setInterval(changeHungerMood, 5000);
mistakeCheck = setInterval(mistakeCheck, 5000);
}
```

Comment: what happens? what goes wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval ?

Comment: maybe this ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/32081949/1447675

Comment: The timer doesn't resume.

Comment: timer can not be resumed, because only start and stop is possible.