# How to repeat `setInterval`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How can i repeat `setInterval`?**

So, i have a function (Duration = 19sec for 1 itteration).

First 4 seconds - label is "text 1",
Next 7 seconds - label is "text 2" 
And next 8 seconds - label is "text 3".

And after 19s it should repeat (I have `var` of itterations - `newCurrentElement`) and i also have the hole duration of the function (`timeNewCurremtElement`).

`timeNewCurremtElement` and `newCurrentElement` are known, so you shouldn't worry about it.

I have tried to make a loop (`for`), but that did't work.

```
function TextChanger() {
    counter = 0;

    clearInterval(timer);

    function TextChanger_Interval(){
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            counter++;

            if (counter <= 3) {
                $('#in-hold-out').html("Inhale");

            } else if (counter <= 10) {
                $('#in-hold-out').html("Hold");

            } else if (counter <= 18) {
                $('#in-hold-out').html("Exhale");

            } else {
                counter = 0;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }

        }, 1000);
    }

    TextChanger_Interval();

}

TextChanger();
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32081949/1447675

Comment: I know how to do a loop for `setTimeout`, but i **have to** use `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object with the time for changing the text and the text as value.

To illustrate, this example shows unchanged counting as well. if not used, delete the else part.

```js
setInterval((i => () => {
    const parts = { 0: 'text1', 4: 'text2', 11: 'text3' };
    if (parts[i]) console.log(parts[i]);
    else console.log(i);
    i++;
    i %= 19;
})(0), 1000);
```

Comment: So `i` is the duration of the function, isn't it?

Comment: `i` is the counter for seconds of an interval of 19 seconds.

Comment: It works, thanks!
But after a few itterations, time become less or something like that.
I think it happens bcz of `i %- 19`
How could i change this line?

Comment: it takes an interval of 19 calls with an timout interval of 1000 ms. what is exactly the problem?

Comment: So, i would try to explain. With every single itteration text changes faster. 1 itteration - in time. For 8th itteration it changes to "Text 2" in 2 seconds (not in 4 seconds as it was at first time)

Comment: Okey, then i am wrong. But what's the line which does this  "reducing" of time

Comment: maybe you have a problem with the interval itself. this is not an accurate method for getting exact intervals. if you need a more precise time keeper by using the time itself and take a smaller interval and look ath the time's delta to the start time and the number iterations.

Comment: I am not sure that it's the problem with `setInterval` itself. I just can't belive. May be something else went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```
  let counter = 0;
  function TextChanger() {

    if (counter <= 3) {
      console.log(0);
    } else if (counter <= 10) {
      console.log(1);
    } else if (counter <= 18) {
      console.log(3);
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++
  }
  setInterval(TextChanger, 1000);
```