# How can I chain functions asynchronously using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was asked to create such an object called `foo` that can chain the function `log` and `wait`.

For example:

```js
foo.log('breakfast').wait(3000).log('lunch').wait(3000).log('dinner');
```

In this scenario it prints `breakfast` first, waits 3 seconds, prints `lunch`, and then after 3 seconds it prints `dinner`.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. What did I miss?

```js
var foo = {
  log: function(text){
    console.log(text);
    return foo;
  },

  wait: function(time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      return foo;
    }, time);
  }
}

foo.log('breakfast').wait(3000).log('lunch').wait(3000).log('dinner');
```

Comment: The problem is in wait function I guess - setTimeout returns immediately and it returns nothing, so calling log on nothing gives an error.

Comment: @kiner_shah what's the correct way to achieve it? I have no idear how can I make it wait and then return the object again.

Comment: Maybe make wait a async function and then define sleep function as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235

Comment: it looks a bit like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32081949/1447675

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's always better to use promises. An implementation of this functionality could be;

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this.promise = Promise.resolve();
  }
  log(txt){
    this.promise = this.promise.then(_ => console.log(txt))
    return this;
  }
  wait(ms){
    this.promise = this.promise.then(_ => new Promise(v => setTimeout(v,ms)));
    return this;
  }
}
  
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.log("happy").wait(1000).log("new").wait(1000).log("year");
```

Comment: Woah what socery is this? Thanks so much and I have to check the Promise and take it in for a moment! Salute and happy new year to you sir!

Comment: You might want to make the object thenable, so that one can `await foo`. Also consider making it immutable, so that you can reuse an object without conflicts between two strands of execution.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. Actually i tried to simplify a continuity pattern (having a resolved promise at hand in advance) within the context of the question. Perhaps it would be an overkill to present any further here. However i would still prefer to have the `promise` property as a private instance field like `this.#promise` rather freezing the object. As per thenability, the approach i have here is in fact forms the building blocks of my Asynchronous Queue ([AQ](https://github.com/kedicesur/AQ)) library which i believe does such things.

Answer (score 13):

For the record, [Redu's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541130/how-can-i-chain-functions-asynchronously-using-javascript/70541273#70541273) without the [class sugar](https://everyday.codes/javascript/please-stop-using-classes-in-javascript/).

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5b6wz1?file=index.js)

```js
const foo = {
  promise: Promise.resolve(),
  log(txt) {
    this.promise.then(_ => console.log(txt));
    return this;
  },
  wait(ms) {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(_ => new Promise(v => setTimeout(v, ms)));
    return this;
  }
};

// OR
const Foo = (defaultMs = 1000) => {
  let promised = Promise.resolve();
  return {
    log(txt) {
      promised.then(_ => console.log(txt));
      return this;
    },
    wait: function(ms) {
      promised = promised.then( _=> 
        new Promise( rs => setTimeout(rs, ms || defaultMs) ) );
      return this;
    }
  };
};

foo.log("Happy").wait(1000).log("new").wait(1000).log("year");
Foo().wait(3000)
  .log(`** From Foo ;)`).log(`Happy`).wait().log("new").wait().log("year");
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the call to `wait` inside the previous one, and as the last item, like a recursive function.

```js
meals=['breakfast','elevenses','lunch','afternoon tea','dinner','supper'];
c=0;
wait=t=>{setTimeout(function() {
      if (c<meals.length) document.write(meals[c++],'<br>');wait(500);
    }, t);}

wait(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by @James 's solution, which is partially wrong because the log messages are in the reverse order, but he does not use `Promise`s. I still think that @Redu 's solution should be the accepted one (after all if you can use `Promise`s, that is perfect), but this one is interesting too in my opinion:

```js
const foo1 = {
    incrementalTimeout: 0,
    nextActions: [],
    log(text) {
        const textLog = () => { console.log(text); };
        if (this.incrementalTimeout == 0)
            textLog();
        else
            this.nextActions.push(textLog);
        return this;
    },
    wait(time) {
        let newObj = {...this, incrementalTimeout: this.incrementalTimeout + time, nextActions: []};
        setTimeout(() => { newObj.nextActions.forEach((action) => action()); } , newObj.incrementalTimeout);
        return newObj;
    }
}
foo1.log('breakfast').wait(1000).log('lunch').wait(3000).log('dinner');
```

The idea is that I do not immediately log `text` but I `push` a lambda with the `console.log` in an array that is going to be called after the correct timeout expires.

I run all the `log` and `wait` operations one after the other, but I keep track of the seconds to wait before executing the actions. Every time a new `wait` is called, the `incrementalTimeout` is increased by `time`. To keep the `nextActions` belonging to different time frames separated, I return a `newObj` every time, more or less like @James does.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter, within `Promise` (not recommended).

```
Promise.prototype.log = function(txt) {
    return this.then(() => console.log(txt))
}

Promise.prototype.wait = function(ms) {
    return this.then(() => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)))
}

var foo = Promise.resolve()
foo.log('breakfast').wait(3000).log('lunch').wait(3000).log('dinner')
```

Comment: Very much not recommended: Promise.prototype is broken now for other users of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without promises:

```js
const foo = {
    log(text) {
        return {...foo, start: () => {
            this.start();
            console.log(text);
        }};
    },
    wait(time) {
        return {...foo, start: () => {
            setTimeout(this.start, time);
        }};
    },
    start() {}
};
foo.log('breakfast').wait(3000).log('lunch').wait(3000).log('dinner').start();
```

The functions `foo.log()` and `foo.wait()` return immediately, returning a modified clone of `foo`. A clone is made using `{...foo}`, but with the `start()` function modified so that it calls the caller's `this.start()` followed by the new operation. When the chain is complete you call `start()` to start the actions.

Comment: This implicit linked list you're building is interesting - unfortunately `wait` runs it in the wrong order

Comment: @Bergi I agree, that is an interesting idea, I have recycled it in my answer if you want to take a look.